# Customize the legend elements

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to customize the legend box elements .Please check the screenshot

[image: legend]

(I want to remove the highlighted information... it's the map service name and symbol in ArcMap)

How its possible? Is there any way or are there any parameters in the legend constructor??

I tried to modify following code but it was not successful...

Code: 
`dojo.connect(map,'onLayersAddResult',function(results){
          var layerInfo = dojo.map(results, function(layer,index){
            return {***layer: abc,title: 'new legend'***};
          });
          if(layerInfo.length > 0){
            var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
              map:map,
              layerInfos:layerInfo
            },"legendDiv");
            legendDijit.startup();
          }
        });`

Comment: Software Details: ArcGIS Server 10.1 & ArcGIS Java script API 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

go to the table of contents and open the properties of the layer.  it looks like you are doing categories for symbols, so uncheck "all other value" on the symbology tab.

now open the legend properties.  uncheck "show" for the legend.  next, find the style button for the legend and change it to something that is more to your liking.

this should get it down to the required items,

-GM

Comment: Hello gm70560, Thanks for your reply with example link. I will try it and let you know.. thanks once again : )

Comment: Hi gm70560, I did changes in ArcMap & its works successfully  : )

Answer (score 1):

Some good references can be found [HERE](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/66991-Legend-Title-Layer-Names?highlight=hide%20legend%20title)

essentially, you are going to have to modify your CSS.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for your reply..I will check out and let you know.. Thank you : )

Comment: Hi Craig, Its works successfully : )